# Chaining promises in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

In angular JS i am having unexpected behovier. I have a log in controller where when i execute Log in function

```
$scope.Login = function () {

    AuthService.login($scope.credentials).then(function(response){
        $location.path('/categories');
    },
     function(error){
        $scope.error_exist = true;
     switch(error.ExceptionMessage){
        case "201" :
             $scope.error = "The emailAddress/password pair don't match an existing member"; break;
        case "210" :
             $scope.error = "Value cannot be null missing Email Address and/or password."; break;
        case "202" :
             $scope.error = "The email address you are using isn't confirmed. Please see your inbox for further instructions."; break;
        default : 
             $scope.error = "Error with the server";
     }
    });
};
```

What happens is that the log in function in `AuthService` get executed then when it hit `AccountService.GetUserAccounts` which is another function in a service it calls back `$location.path('/categories');` which were in the Log in controller after that it continues to execute normally what i want is to call `$location.path('/categories');` after Log in function in `AuthService` get finished.
her is the `AuthService`

```
return $http.post(AuthentoctionControllerUrl, credentials).success(function(response){
               Session.create(response.Name,response.id, response.UserMail);
               AccountService.GetUserAccounts(response.id).then(function(){
                  var acc = AccountService.getAccounts();
                  AccountService.SetUserAccount(acc[0], response.UserMail).then(function(){
                      accIsSet.accSet = true;
                  },
                  function(error){
                      console.log(error);
                  });
               },
               function(error){
                   console.log(result);
               });

            deferred.resolve(response);
           }).error(function(error){
               deferred.reject(error);
           });

            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

Also `AccountService`

```
AccountFactory.GetUserAccounts = function(userID){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            return $http({method : "post", url:ConfigService.baseUrl+UserURl, data: userID})
                         .success(function(response){
                            for(var i = 0; i<response.length; i++)
                            userAccounts.push(response[i].AccName);
                            $cookieStore.put("userAccounts",userAccounts);
                            deferred.resolve(response);
                         }).error(function(error){
                            deferred.reject(error);
                            console.log(error);
                         });
                return deferred.promise;
        };

        AccountFactory.SetUserAccount = function(accName, userMail){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
                        return $http({method : "post", url:ConfigService.baseUrl+AccountUrl+"?accName="+accName+"&userMail="+userMail})
                         .success(function(response){
                            $cookieStore.put('AuthorizationHeader', response.Token);
                            AccSession.create(response.IsAdmin);
                            deferred.resolve(response);
                         }).error(function(error){
                            deferred.reject(error);
                            console.log(error);
                         });
                return deferred.promise;
        };
AccountFactory.getAccounts = function(){
    if(userAccounts)
        return userAccounts;
    else
        return null;
};
```

Her is an edit of the code and i still get the same behavior.

```
 authService.login = function(credentials) {
           return $http.post(AuthentoctionControllerUrl, credentials).success(function(response){
               Session.create(response.Name,response.id, response.UserMail);
              return AccountService.GetUserAccounts(response.id).then(function(){
                  return AccountService.getAccounts();
              }).then(function(acc) {
                 return AccountService.SetUserAccount(acc[0], response.UserMail);
              }).then(function() {
                      accIsSet.accSet = true;
              });
           });
        };
 AccountFactory.GetUserAccounts = function(userID){
           return $http({method : "post", url:ConfigService.baseUrl+UserURl, data: userID})
                         .success(function(response){
                            console.log("ssss");
                            for(var i = 0; i<response.length; i++)
                            userAccounts.push(response[i].AccName);
                            $cookieStore.put("userAccounts",userAccounts);
                             return response;
                         });
        };

        AccountFactory.SetUserAccount = function(accName, userMail){
                        return $http({method : "post", url:ConfigService.baseUrl+AccountUrl+"?accName="+accName+"&userMail="+userMail})
                         .success(function(response){
                            $cookieStore.put('AuthorizationHeader', response.Token);
                            AccSession.create(response.IsAdmin);
                            return response;
                         });
        };

        AccountFactory.getAccounts = function(){
            if(userAccounts)
                return userAccounts;
            else
                return null;
        };

        return AccountFactory;
    }]);
```

Answer (score 2):

**$http** services when invoked, returns a promise. A promise has methods **.then()**, **.catch()**, **.finally()** which returns a promise as well. Additionally, the **$http** service's **.success()** and **.error()** methods returns a promise. Thus, creating a promise via `$q.defer()` and resolving it like that is redundant. If you want to get the response value on success you can simply return it as shown below.

Change your `AuthService.login()` to return something like this:

```
return $http.post(AuthentoctionControllerUrl, credentials)
    .success(function(response) {
        Session.create(response.Name,response.id, response.UserMail);

        return AccountService.GetUserAccounts(response.id)
            .then(function(acc) {
                return AccountService.SetUserAccount(acc[0], response.UserMail);
            }).then(function() {
                accIsSet.accSet = true;
            });
    });
```

and your `AccountFactory` to this:

```
AccountFactory.GetUserAccounts = function(userID){
    return $http({method : "post", url:ConfigService.baseUrl+UserURl, data: userID})
         .success(function(response){
            for(var i = 0; i<response.length; i++)
                userAccounts.push(response[i].AccName);
            $cookieStore.put("userAccounts",userAccounts);
            return response;
         });
};

AccountFactory.SetUserAccount = function(accName, userMail){
    return $http({method : "post", url:ConfigService.baseUrl+AccountUrl+"?accName="+accName+"&userMail="+userMail})
        .success(function(response){
            $cookieStore.put('AuthorizationHeader', response.Token);
            AccSession.create(response.IsAdmin);
            return response;
        });
};
```

Note: Error Handling should be within the controller logic, unless for special cases wherein you need to change some states within the factory/service itself then that would be an exception. If you would catch the errors, make sure to return the response so that error handlers within the controllers/factories/services that depend on it can still access the response.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out error handling. but i am still having the same behavior where $location.path('/categories'); get executed before  var acc = AccountService.getAccounts(); in the Auth service

Comment: I have made minor changes in AuthService.login() to show how chaining promises work. Check if it works.

Comment: AccountService.getAccounts(); dose not make HTTP request i will edit my question to show it sorry and i am still have the same beauvoir

Comment: I have updated `AuthService.login()` since `AccountFactory.GetUserAccounts()` returns the response on success it should be available when invoking `.then()`. Please check update.

Comment: I followed your instructions i could post my edit your Code ? i get  same behavior

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58891/discussion-between-ryeballar-and-user2918388).

Answer (score 1):

I manged to solve the problem by the help of @ryeballar

```
authService.login = function(credentials) {
            var defferd = $q.defer();
            $http.post(AuthentoctionControllerUrl, credentials).success(function(response){
               Session.create(response.Name,response.id, response.UserMail);
              return AccountService.GetUserAccounts(response.id).then(function(acc){
                  if(acc.data.length !=0)
                    return AccountService.SetUserAccount(acc.data[0].AccName, response.UserMail);
                  else
                      return 0;
              }).then(function(data) {
                  if(data)
                    accIsSet.accSet = true;

                  defferd.resolve(response);
              });
           }).error(function(error){
                defferd.reject(error);
            });
                return defferd.promise;
        };
```

Modified the Auth service to resolve the promise at the end of success method so the method in the controller will fire as expected